# add class to first and last element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class to the first and last '.sub' between the two '.heading' class with jQuery.

```
    <table>
        <tr class="heading"></tr>
        <tr class="sub top-box"></tr>
        <tr class="sub"></tr>
        <tr class="sub bottom-box"></tr>
        <tr class="heading"></tr>
        <tr class="sub top-box"></tr>
        <tr class="sub"></tr>
        <tr class="sub"></tr>
        <tr class="sub"></tr>
        <tr class="sub bottom-box"></tr>
    </table>
```

I try this, but that's don't work :

```
    jQuery('.heading').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery('.sub:first').nextUntil('.heading').toggleClass('top-box');
        jQuery('.sub:last').nextUntil('.heading').toggleClass('bottom-box');
    });
```

Comment: Try $('.sub').first() and $('.sub').last()

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the next item with class `sub` after the first `.heading` item, and the `.sub` right before the last `.heading` item?

```js
jQuery('.heading').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(".heading").first().next(".sub").toggleClass("top-box");
  jQuery(".heading").last().prev(".sub").toggleClass("bottom-box");
});
```

```css
.top-box {background: red;}
.bottom-box {background: blue;}
.heading {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="heading"><td>HEADING</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub top-box"><td>sub</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub bottom-box"><td>sub</td></tr>
  <tr class="heading"><td>HEADING</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub top-box"><td>sub</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub bottom-box"><td>sub</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok thank you that's work but not for the next .heading class

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `:first`/`:last` selector along with `prev()`/`next()` methods.

```js
$('.heading:first').next('.sub').addClass("top-box")
$('.heading:last').prev('.sub').addClass("bottom-box")
```

```css
.top-box{
  background-color:yellow
}
.bottom-box{
  background-color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="heading"><td>heading</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub "><td>sub1</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub "><td>sub</td></tr>
    <tr class="heading"><td>heading</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub"><td>sub2</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
    <tr class="sub"><td>sub</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... its possible to make it more fancy :D

```
jQuery('.heading').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var i = 0;
        $('.heading').each(function(){
          if(i % 2 = 0){
            jQuery(this).next(".sub").toggleClass("top-box");
          }else{
            jQuery(this).prev(".sub").toggleClass("bottom-box");
          }
          i++;
        });
    });
```